# How to get Google Feed API to display CDATA?

Tags: javascript, rss, cdata, google-feed-api

I am using GoogleFeed API to display an RSS feed as HTML:

```
var feedcontainer=document.getElementById("feeddiv")
var feedurl="MY FEED URL"
var feedlimit=20
var rssoutput=""

function rssfeedsetup(){
var feedpointer=new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl) //Google Feed API method
feedpointer.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT)
feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit) //Google Feed API method
feedpointer.load(displayfeed) //Google Feed API method
}

function displayfeed(result){
if (!result.error){
var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++)
rssoutput+="<a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "' style='text-decoration:none'>" + "<h1 class='pub'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</h1>" + "</a>" + new Date(thefeeds[i].publishedDate) + thefeeds[i].content + "<p class='text-small-hilite'><a href='" +thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + "Read full post" + "</a></p>"
rssoutput+=""
feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
}
else
alert("Error fetching feeds!")
}

window.onload=function(){
rssfeedsetup()
}
```

I want to also display as HTML a CDATA element inside my tag . I've tried .xmlNode.getElementsByTagName but that hasn't worked.

```
<item>
<title>
MY TITLE
</title>
<link>MY URL</link>
<comments>MY URL</comments>
 <pubDate>Fri, 17 Oct 2014 19:06:53 +0000</pubDate>
 <dc:creator>
 <![CDATA[ MY AUTHOR ]]>
 </dc:creator>
```

Is it possible to get the text within the CDATA "MY AUTHOR" to display as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

That tag has the dc namespace, so you could use [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getelementsbytagnamens.asp) method inside your for-loop like this:

```
var creator = thefeeds[i].xmlNode.getElementsByTagNameNS(
              'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/', 'creator')[0].innerHTML;
```

But if you just want contents of dc:creator, it is probably the same as `thefeeds[i].author`. The [Feed API's JSON documentation](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#resultJson) can be helpful.

Tip: use your [browser's developer tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) and set a breakpoint inside your for-loop, then you can see what the object contains:

[image]